# user unable to login to subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

> i have a parent site site-1 and few subsites like
> subsite-1,subsite-2,subsite-3. in subsites am stopped inheritance
> permission from parent site. so here my requirement is different
> permissions for parent site and every subsite.
>
> subsite-1 users can't access parent site and other subsites. but when am added user in
> subsite-1 he is unable to login in subsite-1. am getting message like
> access denied and i sent request and approved also to login. but still
> the user unable to login to subsite-1.
>
> **Awaiting approval. We'll let you know about any updates**. am getting this same message if am given full control permission to subsite-1.

Comment: Sometimes there might be resources like style sheets and other js files in the custom master page that is stored in the parent site. Do you have any of those ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Subsite with site collection admin access, 
Site Settings - > Site Permission -> Check Permission

First thing you should see if user has permission set, if not grant permission from here..definitely you are missing something very basic because it should work without issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did tests in my environment, but I didn't reproduce your situation.

I suggest you remove users with this condition from subsite and then add them again.